# HMR not working when using nodemon

Tags: reactjs, webpack-dev-server, nodemon, webpack-hot-middleware

I have an app that is using express to serve some API calls and webpack to server some static assets in development. All works ok until I bring nodemon into the setup.
When I run my app using nodemon I get this error when I update a file on the React side (client side).

> GET http://localhost:3004/__webpack_hmr
>   net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING

If I run my app without nodemon the HMR works perfect and all updates and reloads the React modules.

In my package.json file I have the following scripts. 
The start one works fine but the dev one using nodemon causes the error when a change is made to a React component.

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server/app.js",
    "dev": "nodemon server/app.js",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config ./webpack/webpack.prod.config.js --progress --colors",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"
  },
```

**Any ideas what might be causing this?**

Here is my entry point in my webpack config file.

```
  entry: [
    `${ROOT_DIR}/js/index`,
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client'
  ]
```

Here is my webpack setup with webpackHotMiddleware which I call in my app.js and pass in App to it. App being my express server.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
const webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware');
const webpackConfig = require('../../webpack/webpack.dev.config.js');
const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);

const devOptions = {
    noInfo: true,
    publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
    stats: { colors: true },
    historyApiFallback: true
}
// WEBPACK MIDDLEEWARE
function setupWebpackMiddleware( app ){
  app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler));
  app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, devOptions));
}

module.exports = {setupWebpackMiddleware}
```

Using the following versions.

```
     "webpack": "^2.2.1"
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "~1.16.2",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.16.1"
```

Comment: When using a webpack react project and another api server, just let the site be served from webpack and in package.json set proxy to your api server. So api calls get piped through.

Comment: Any example of that ?

Comment: pretty much like this: [create-react-app-express-backend](https://daveceddia.com/create-react-app-express-backend/)

Comment: Thanks XDreamCoding i'll have a look at this and see if I can make it work.